# How can I break out of a chain of RxJava calls?

Tags: android, rest, rx-java

I have the following set of RxJava operators:

```
  currentUser = mApi.getUserById(userToken, userId, userId)
                    .onErrorReturn(throwable -> null)
                    .map(userSet -> userSet.getUsers().get(0))
                    .doOnNext(user -> {
                        user.setToken(userToken);
                    })
                    .toBlocking()
                    .first();
```

The problem here is that the `doOnNext()` call and the `map()` call *could* be operating on null inputs. I could check within each of these calls for a null input, and act accordingly, but what I'd *like* to do is simply break the chain of operations and return a `null` value to `currentUser`.

Is this possible if I restructure my RxJava operations somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just move the `onErrorReturn` operator to the end of the chain, before `toBlocking()`. Then the exception caught at `getUserById` would propagate through the following operator's error handling (so the `map` and `doOnNext` won't be executed) until hitting the `onErrorReturn` and returning the null.

For example, this code prints `null`:

```
Integer myInt = Observable.<Integer> error(new RuntimeException())
            .doOnNext(item -> System.out.println("doOnNextInvoked"))
            .onErrorReturn(throwable -> null)
            .toBlocking().first();

System.out.println(myInt);
```

While this one:

```
Integer myInt = Observable.<Integer> error(new RuntimeException())
            .onErrorReturn(throwable -> null)
            .doOnNext(item -> System.out.println("doOnNextInvoked"))
            .toBlocking().first();

System.out.println(myInt);
```

prints

```
doOnNextInvoked
null
```

So we see that the `doOnNext` was invoked in the second case, but not the first.